# In terms of gravitational waves, what terms or components are actually embedded within $h_{\mu\nu}$?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, gravitational-waves

In terms of gravitational waves:
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\text{ with } |h_{\mu\nu}|\ll 1$$

The components of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ are $[-1,1,1,1]$ which expresses flat Minkowski spacetime. However, within $h_{\mu\nu}$ what does the $A$ in $A\cos(kz-\omega t)$ equate to which is embedded in $h_{xx}$, $h_{xy}$, $h_{yx}$ , and $h_{yy}$?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking about the physical interpretation of the components $h_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Hi, I edited and updated my question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the value of $h$, what does $h$ equal?

Comment: You haven't really clarified the question. But anyway, $h_{\mu\nu}$ is not given a priori. It's an unknown, to be found from the Einstein equations.

Comment: My apologies. similar to how the Schwarzschild metric has non-zero terms that are $\Big(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\Big)$, $-\Big(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\Big)^{-1}$,$-r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2)$. Does $h_{xx}$, $h_{xy}$, $h_{yx}$ and $h_{yy}$ have an equivalent analog?

Comment: thank you for  being patient with me. So in the non-zero components of $h_{\mu\nu}$ I would find terms similar to $A\cos(kz-\omega t)$

Comment: Then this is crux of where I'm getting at. What determines the value of $A$ in $A\cos(kz-\omega t)$, where is its value derived from; what equation computes it?

Comment: The [quadrupole formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula) is usually used to compute the amplitude. You have to know how the mass quadrupole moment of the source is changing.

Comment: I’ve deleted all my earlier comments, since they no longer make sense after your edit.

Comment: I understand, one last thing. Flat Minkowski spacetime is taken to be flat when there is no curvature denoted by (-1,1,1,1]. However, in other metrics such as the Schwarzschild metric the non-zero elements diverge from 1 the greater the curvature of spacetime. My confusion is this. For a gravitational wave $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\text{ with } |h_{\mu\nu}|\ll 1$, Here it infers that when $h_{\mu\nu} = 1$, not zero, spacetime curvature is extreme. But Minkowski spacetime indicates 1 is the lowest possible value when spacetime is flat. Are these '1's" not the same thing?

Comment: *Are these '1's" not the same thing?* 1 is 1. I can’t figure out what you’re asking, and comments are not the place to ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we are far from the gravitational wave emitting source, we can treat the effect of the wave on the source-free background as a tiny perturbation. The source-free background is modeled as a flat spacetime ($\eta_{ab}$) and the weak perturbation ($h_{ab}$) caused by the wave can then be treated in a linearized fashion. The resulting metric can be written as $$g_{ab} = \eta_{ab} + h_{ab} \,. \tag{1}$$

Linearized here means that on substituting the above equation in [Einstein's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), only terms linear in $h_{ab}$ are retained.

Introducing Minkowski coordinates $x^a := (t,\vec{x})$ where $\vec{x} := (x,y,z)$  and working in the so-called *[Lorentz gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition)* condition, one can substitute Eq. (1) in the LHS of source-free Einstein's equations $$ R_{ab}  = 0 \,,$$
where $R_{ab}$ is the Ricci curvature tensor to get
$$\nabla^c \nabla_c h_{ab} = \left( - \frac{\partial^2}{c^2 \partial t^2} + \nabla^2 \right) h_{ab} =  0 \,. \tag{2} $$

Under such a setting, it can be seen that  Eq.(2) represents a wave equation. Comparing this to the case of the EM waves, $h_{ab}$ plays the role of the electromagnetic 4-potential $A^a$, and Eq. (2) is similar to source-free Maxwell's equations.

So, we conclude that the metric perturbation $h_{ab}$ describes a gravitational wave (moving at speed $c$) with the wave being ripples in the flat metric $\eta_{ab}$, that is, the background spacetime.

We would like to find the form of $h_{ab}$ that satisfies the wave equation Eq.(2). From EM, we know a solution to such a wave equation as
$$ h_{ab}  = A_{ab} e^{i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x} - \omega_{\vec{k}} t)} \,,$$ where as usual $\vec{k}, \omega_{\vec{k}}$ represents the wave number and angular frequency and $A_{ab} \in \mathbb{R}$ **is the wave's amplitude**.

---

From the comments below your question I realize that you want to know the exact form of $A_{ab}$. This cannot be answered unless we know the nature of the source that is producing the gravitational radiation. The easiest of all is when the source (as *@Ghoster* pointed out) can be treated in the so-called [quadrupole approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula). In such a case the spatial components of $A_{ab}$ (assuming $\mu, \nu$ runs over spatial index) can be determined from $$\bar{h}_{\mu \nu} = \frac{2 G}{c^4 r} \ddot{I}_{\mu\nu}(t - r/c)$$ $r$ being the distance to the source and ${I}_{\mu\nu}$ the quadrupole moment evaluate at some retarded.

Comment: Thank you! YES!! haha, that is exactly what I'm trying to determine - the exact form of $A_{ab}$. This term here $\frac{2 G}{c^4 r} \ddot{I}_{\mu\nu}$ almost looks like $2GM/rc^2$. Do you happen to know what the value of exact form of $\ddot{I}_{\mu\nu}$ is or where I can find it?

Comment: @AnthonySmith Different systems have different mass quadrupole moments. It depends on how mass is distributed within the system, as you can see from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole).

Comment: @Ghoster Yes, thats correct and I'm missing the time retarded term too. I will add that in now.

Comment: @AnthonySmith For the case of two point masses in Keplerian orbit you can follow this paper (see section 3) https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.131.435